# Error when expand/collapse page section

Tags: error, page-layout

I have observed the below on the basic Account page in Salesforce's Lightning page (not a custom code page layout).

I am receiving the following error when I expand/collapse a page section on any object.  Seems to coincide with Winter '19 release.

[image: This page has an error]

Text from "Technical Stuff" section of error:

> [Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.]
>   {anonymous} ()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:844:220
>   xH.B.Nd()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:844:66
>   IH.B.Nd()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:859:263
>   LE.T.sw()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:545:116
>   {anonymous}()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:535:330
>   LE.T.yd()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:535:304
>   LE.T.hd()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_prod.js:544:263
>   a.removeAll()@https://niimbl.lightning.force.com/libraries/force/recordLayoutLibrary/storageKeyCacheWrapper.js:7:456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cache and restarting the browser seemed to resolve the issue.